# Push Notification Not Arriving from Parse Cloud Code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

I wrote a simple job to try sending a push notification to myself. Here's the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("testPush", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    installationQuery.equalTo("user", "6t1JIuNqe1");  // I triple checked - this is the value of my user in the installation table.
    Parse.Push.send({
        where: installationQuery,
        data: {
            alert: "Test"
        },
    }, {
        success: function() {
            console.log("The Push Test Worked!");
            status.success("All done with the push test!");
        }, error: function(error) {
            console.error("Something bad happened " + error);
            status.error("Something bad happened during the Parse test...");
        }
    });
});
```

Although it logs in Parse that the job was run successfully, I never see a notification appear on my iPhone. I checked in Settings - it's all set up properly there (notifications are allowed to appear and should appear as banners, they should show up in notification center, they should show up on my lock screen). And yet the notification never appears.

What more do I need to check? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see any message from log? Whats the data type of `user` column in installation, string or pointer?

Comment: @eth3lbert - Yes, I see the message "The Push Test Worked!". `user` is a pointer... have I set up the `.equalTo()` improperly for dealing with pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer field should work with an instance.

Try replacing `installationQuery.equalTo("user", "6t1JIuNqe1");` with the following:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.id = '6t1JIuNqe1';    
installationQuery.equalTo('user', user);
```

Comment: I will try this tonight and let you know if it works.